# Django Tastypie POST request for OneToOne relation

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie, one-to-one

I have recently started django-tastypie and so far loving the framework. With said that, I am getting below issue on POST for OneToOne relation to model and spent good amount of time but couldn't figured whats missing. Here is the Model and Resource code -

**Model**

```
class Question(TimeStampedModel):
    question_title = models.CharField("question title", max_length=100)     
    question_desc = models.TextField("question description", max_length=1000)
    .......
```

Second model is having OneToOne relation with Question -

```
class QuestionAnswer(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.OneToOneField(Question)
    .....
```

**Resource**

QuestionAnswerResource -

```
class QuestionAnswerResource(ModelResource):
    question = fields.ForeignKey('myapp.api.QuestionResource', 'question')

    class Meta:
        queryset = QuestionAnswer.objects.all()
        resource_name='questionanswer'
```

QuestionResource -

```
class QuestionResource(ModelResource):
    questionanswer = fields.OneToOneField('myapp.api.QuestionAnswerResource', 'questionanswer', full=True) 

    class Meta:
        queryset = Question.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'question'
```

With the above setup, I get correct response on GET with Question instance along with its answer attribute. However when I try to POST data to save question/answer on this one it fails with below error -

> "{"error_message": "", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call
>   last):\n\n  File
>   \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 192,
>   ...................................................................................... line 636, in hydrate\n
>   value = super(ToOneField, self).hydrate(bundle)\n\n  File
>   \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\", line 154, in
>   hydrate\n    elif self.attribute and getattr(bundle.obj,
>   self.attribute, None):\n\n  File
>   \"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py\", line 343, in **get**\n    raise
>   self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist\n\nDoesNotExist\n"}"

Can someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: This happened to me when I forgot to add resource URI in the call.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this:

```
questionanswer = fields.OneToOneField('myapp.api.QuestionAnswerResource', 'questionanswer', full=True)
```

causes problem. There is no `questionanswer` field in your `Question` model and Django expects that.

To test, you may want to see whether you can create instances in the shell. [Tastypie docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#toonefield) say the following about the `ToOneField`:

> This subclass requires Django’s ORM layer to work properly.

and I think this might not be the case here.

To provide answers for a question you may want to set [`related_name`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name), like so:

```
question = fields.ForeignKey('myapp.api.QuestionResource', 'question', related_name = 'questionanswer')
```